# SQL Tables structure and relationship for Quizz

Tags: sql, mysql, drupal

I'm developing a simple custom Drupal Module for creating Quizz, and I need some help with the SQL part.

I'd like to keep a trace of registered used who answered the Quizz, but don't know how to build the relationship.

Basically, I have 2 tables with these columns:

`Users`:

- `id`
- `name`
- `email`
- `status`

and

`Content_Type_Quizz`:

- `id`
- `start date`
- `end date`
- `good answer`
- `explanation`

There's also a third table with the quizz answers, but I don't think it would help in my situation.

Should I add a field in the `Content_Type_Quizz` table with the user id? Or create a new table `Content_Type_Quizz_AnsweredBy` with the Quizz id, the answer and the User id?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you aware there's already a Quiz module for Drupal that does everything you've described here? http://drupal.org/project/quiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a many to many relation; a quizz can be answered by many users and a user can answer multiple quizzes. You will need 3 tables: users, quizzes and quizz_answer (or quizz_user).
The users table will hold the users, quizzes will hold the quizzes and quizz_answer will hold the user answer to the quizz.
I think the quizz_answer table should have 3 column; user_id, quizz_id and the answer to the quizz. I believe you need to revisit your quizz table structure because I don't understand the good answer and explanation columns.